# Generic use of DropDownListFor with reflections

Tags: c#, reflection

I've always used `DropDownListFor` like this

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PropertyOfTheModel, SelectionList)
```

this works fine as long as you know the exact name of the property you're trying to build a dropdown list on (in this case: `PropertyOfTheModel`).

Now I have a different task. My model contains a fixed property, declared as `object` and called `FormModel`. Using reflections assume I'd like to build a dropdown for everyone of the properties contained in `FormModel`. Thanks to the attributes I've managed to solve the `SelectionList` part, I now have to write the first argument but I have no idea on how to do it.

```
foreach (var property in Model.FormModel.GetType().GetProperties())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FormModel.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name), SelectList)
}
```

The code above is not working: how should I write it? I have no experience in writing lambda expressions: is there any alternative to generate a dropdownlist which automagically gets the correct `selected` attribute just by passing in the property and the selection list? Or do I have to write the expression? Thanks!

this is the error I get:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions.

Comment: Are all the properties in FormModel public? Perhaps you need to pass BindingFlags into GetProperty to filter out non-public properties?

Comment: There's a portion of the code which I didn't posted but assures that only public properties arrives at DropDownListFor. Didn't posted as I think it was not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had time to try this out yet, but the stumbling block may be that the code is trying to bind `PropertyInfo`, not the actual property on the class. I would give this a shot:

```cs
foreach (var property in Model.FormModel.GetType().GetProperties())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => property.Name, SelectList)
}
```

Comment: please note that property.Name is a string and, most importantly, that I want to create a droplist for m.FormModel not just m. m is just a generic model which contains (in the property FormModel) the actual model I want to edit. Unfortunately, it is not working :( Thanks for your advice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is as simple as this:

```
@Html.DropDownList(property.Name, SelectList)
```

Don't use the DropDownListFor helper, but DropDownList instead.